# Le proverbe chinois « 雪中送炭 » signifiant littéralement : « faire parvenir le charbon aux gens sous la neige »

Tags: expressions

Est-ce que vous auriez un gros tas de charbon stocké à fournir ? Qui en aurait un besoin plus pressant que les ouvriers qui vont *charbonner* sous la neige ou ceux qui se sont perdus dans le blizzard ? Dans la situation où ils se trouvent, ils n'auront tous qu'une envie, c'est de se réchauffer et vite !

Le proverbe chinois «雪中送炭» que l'on entend souvent dans le cadre professionnel s'emploie pour souligner la nécessité d'agir sans tarder pour un effet maximum, par exemple en faisant parvenir quelque chose aux gens dans le besoin, et au moment opportun, qui plus est. Un geste de bonté, c’est bien gentil en soi, mais franchement, à quoi bon tant de charbon si la neige aura déjà complètement fondu !?

Je cherche un (quasi-)équivalent français à cette expression.

Comment: Est-ce l'aspect urgence ou l'aspect charité le plus important ? J'avoue que j'ai du mal à imaginer un cas d'usage de cette expression, surtout dans un contexte professionnel.

Comment: @guillaume31 C'est 50/50, il s'agit à part égale des deux, je dirais. Par ex.: Merci de m'être venu en aide. J'étais à deux doigts de renoncer à mon projet et voilà que tu m'a sortie du pétrin comme «雪中送炭».

Comment: @Najibidrissi one of the things I find interesting in such questions is that it makes me think about the expressions I know and opens the door to learning new ones from other answers. The same way I like being "forced" to think about grammar of sentences I use as an habit as a native speaker. I know this wasn't the initial purpose, but it kinda shifted towards more of a "French language learners" quite a long time ago already. You still have the possibility to download or flag the question - or even just ignore it - so I don't think there's any need for passive-aggressive comments.

Answer (score 1):

Pour l'aspect "générosité", on pourrait parler de "faire le bon samaritain" (personne qui sauve quelqu'un d'une situation désespérée. Dans le contexte qui a donné lieu à l'expression, le samaritain était par ailleurs un "étranger", pas la personne de qui on s'attendait à recevoir de l'aide.)

Pour l'aspect "bien à propos", on pourrait parler de "tomber à pic" (faire quelque chose au bon moment).

Je ne connais pas de proverbe qui allie ces deux aspects.

Answer (score 0):

La sagesse chinoise n'a pas nécessairement traversé toutes les barrières de la langue :-)

Dans l'immédiat, le plus proche auquel je pense serait

> Parer au plus pressé

Mais c'est très générique et fort peu imagé...

Answer (score 0):

on pourrait dire

> sortir quelqu'un du pétrin

pour le fait de sortir quelqu'un d'une impasse, mais l'aspect d'urgence n'est pas forcément inclus dans cette expression